# How to write numbers in text files in embedded C

Tags: c, file, embedded, printf

I'm working with an EFM32wg280f256 and I would like to debug the code that I'm writing in the following manner: opening a file in SD memory and write the content of the buffers I'm using.

This is a minimal example of my attempt:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "ff.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include "arm_math.h"
#include "audioMoth.h"

#define NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_IN_BUFFERS_DATA       4


static float32_t* buffersDATA[12];


int main(void) {

      //Create buffers
      buffersDATA[0] = (float32_t*)AM_EXTERNAL_SRAM_START_ADDRESS;
      for (int i = 1; i < 12; i += 1) {
          buffersDATA[i] = buffersDATA[i - 1] + NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_IN_BUFFERS_DATA;
      }

      //Example of collected data
      float32_t var0[] = {-29.499557,-67.498978,-54.499176,-53.499191};


      //Pass collected data to one of created buffers
      for (int j = 0; j <NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_IN_BUFFERS_DATA; j+= 1){
          *(buffersDATA[0]+j) = var0[j];
      }


      //Initialize file system
      AudioMoth_enableFileSystem();

      // Write text file
      FIL fpt;
      f_open(&fpt,"dataVAR.txt", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
      for (int i = 0; i <NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_IN_BUFFERS_DATA; i+= 1){
          char str[8];
          sprintf(str, "%d, ", (int)var0[i]);
          f_puts(str,&fpt);
      }
      f_close(&fpt);

      // Write another text file
      FIL fptr;
      f_open(&fptr,"data.txt", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
      for (int i = 0; i <NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_IN_BUFFERS_DATA; i+= 1){
          char str[8];
          sprintf(str, "%d, ", (int)*(buffersDATA[0]+i));
          f_puts(str,&fptr);
      }
      f_close(&fptr);

}
```

Typecasting is because `sprintf` does not support float values, but integer is enough for me to know if I am doing OK or not.

When I open dataVAR.txt:

`-29, -67, -54, -53,`

But data.txt:

`0, 0, 0, 0,`

when they should be the same.

I've tried the same in a executable (adapting it) to verify that I am correctly passing the values (it seems so).

Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For sprintf use `%d` then, if you use int, not `%f`. Also, when you assign bufferData, you are missing & infront: `*(&buffersDATA[0]+j) = var0[j];`

Comment: What makes you think `sprintf` does not support float values? `static float32_t* buffersDATA[12];` is an array of *pointers* to floats. Is that your intention?

Comment: *(buffersDATA[0]+j) = var0[j]; should be *(buffersDATA[0]+j) = &var0[j]; see comment above

Comment: @car00 - tilz0R's first advice is good, the second isn't, because `buffersDATA[0]` is a pointer.

Comment: @tilz0R sorry, I uploaded a old version (I tried directly with floats before). It's corrected now with `%d`. Thanks. About the second, `buffersDATA[0]` is a pointer as @Armali said.

Comment: @th33lf I've tried with floats and only prints `, , , ,` in the text file. I've been reading some threads and I understood that `sprintf`could not have the entired capability (depends on the libraries). About the second, yes, I want to create an array of pointers to use it afterwards.

Comment: The `float*` array doesn't make any sense and that's about it. Either use a `float*` or an array of `float`.

Comment: If you are attempting to store these numbers starting from AM_EXTERNAL_SRAM_START_ADDRESS, then `volatile float32_t* buffersDATA = (float32_t*)AM_EXTERNAL_SRAM_START_ADDRESS;` might be a good place to start. You can then use `buffersDATA` like an array of floats and store numbers in it.

Comment: Embedded implementations may indeed lack FP support in printf() functions.  There's some broken pointer/array usage in the code here.  An "array of pointers" is almost certainly mistaken thinking - if you were going to do that, you'd also have to have other memory to hold the actual data which those pointers can point to.  More typically you have an array of items which you can access individually with a pointer.  Also logging to an SD card for basic debug feels like a last choice or for deployment not initial development, try to get a serial UART going for live debug messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I didn't initialize communication between the microcontroller and the external chip of SRAM.

I did and all worked as expected.